# PCB #/# mil process

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-assembly

I have to design a PCB with QFN (20-PIN QFN
CASE 2059-01) of the MPR121QR2 IC sensor.

I have finished my design and I need to choose a PCB foundry and they have several pricing for different Min. Width and Min. Space (https://www.pcbgogo.com/capabilities.html). I have choose a 6/6 mil process but the spacing of the QFN package is a bit higher than 4 mil but the whole board have routing that has no problem of clearance with 6/6 mil process. They said to me that I can order with 6/6 mil process. Is it really possible to print this QFN package with 6/6 mil process ?

Comment: Nope.  You need to choose a different package or pay for premium PCB service.

Comment: Will PCB manufacturers refuse to print something with finer structures in a coarser process on a best efforts basis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/MPR121.pdf), the QFN package of the MPR121 is 0.2mm pin size with 0.2mm spacing. That equates to just under 8mil/8mil.

You should have no problem designing for this package with a 6mil/6mil design rule. Something like a 10mil pad, 6mil spacing should work fine.

If the spacing had been less than 6mil, then you might get away with it, but probably not. It would certainly not be worth the risk trying.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking on the footprint provided by NXP and it seems that the spacing is much more smaller on the footprint. I will change my footprint to respect the DRC with the 6 mil process.

Comment: @TomCarpenter those are the pin sizes, but what really needs to be taken into consideration is the pad size. The pads should be slightly larger than the pins, and this might lead to much less spacing between the pads. I would like to see the source the OP originally used to generate the footprint, but I expect he'll still need to pay the premium for tighter spacing.

Comment: @DerStrom8 indeed it is, but given it's an 8/8 package, building a 10/6 footprint would be quite acceptable.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Fair point. I'd still like to see the original source though, out of sheer curiosity. I just don't feel like digging to try to find it myself

Answer (score 0):

The resoloution of the photoplotters is generally much finer than the advertised min track/gap. After that you get into a messy world of photoimaging and wet chemistry.

There isn't some hard edge where everything bigger than a threshold will come out fine and everything smaller than that same threshold will fail. As the features get smaller the chances of something going sufficiently wrong to make the board a dud (e.g. a track etched away or a gap bridged) increase. So to make boards with smaller features the board vendor needs to either accept a lower yeild or improve the quality of their process.

It may be that your board vendor feels that a few closely spaced component pads will not affect yield significantly and so is prepared to base their price on the bulk of the board.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the board arrived using the 6/6 mil process and I have chosen a QFN footprint that just fit the MPR121 footprint and not the official footprint from NXP that would require a 4/4 mil process.

4 MPR121 were soldered on the board and all of them are working perfectly.

[image: Board with 4 MPR121 soldered on it]